# Getting a runtime error 438 and not sure why

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I am using MSO Access 2013, and writing some code to open the file dialog for the user to select an Excel file to import information in to a table in the database. I get the Runtime error, and not exactly sure why. Would anyone kindly help with this situation? The code is as follows

```
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWrksht As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim xl As Excel.Application
    Dim xlsht As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim xlWrkBk As Excel.Workbook

    If MsgBox("This will create a new job by importing a Start Up worksheet. 
    Do you want to continue?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Well Startup - Import 
    File") = vbYes Then
    'prompt user for file
    Const msoFileDialogFilePicker As Long = 3
    Dim objDialog As Object
    Dim fPath As String
    Set objDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With objDialog
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Show
        If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
            MsgBox "No file selected."
            Exit Sub
        Else
            fPath = .InitialFileName
        End If
    End With
    'open db and store data in tables
    Set myRec = CurrentDb.openrecordset("WellProject")
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set xlWrksht = xlApp.Open(fPath).Worksheets("1") '<----where I get the error
    Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set xlWrkBk = GetObject(fPath)
    Set xlsht = xlWrkBk.Worksheets(1)
    '1st table
    myRec.AddNew
    myRec.Fields("Job") = xlWrksht.Cells(2, "F")
    myRec.Fields("spud_date") = xlWrksht.Cells(10, "B")
    myRec.Update
    Else: Exit Sub
    End If
```

The directory path is stored in the variable fPath. This works fine. I believe the issue would be somewhere with the Excel file, but not sure. Any ideas? Thanks everyone!

Comment: `Excel.Application` does not have a method `Open`. It has a property `Workbooks`, that does have `Open`.

Comment: So would I change it to something like this: Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Workbooks")

Comment: `Set xlWrksht = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(fPath).Worksheets(1)` - you wouldn't quote the "1" unless the sheet name is literally "1".  If you just want the first sheet then pass a number.